# Spring Boot testing, migrate from 1.3 to 1.5

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-test

I updated my spring-boot project from 1.3.x to 1.5.2. The testing framework has "changed" and I am trying to migrate my code. The response status code from the RestTemplate should be 401, but when I change the code to the new "structure" I get a 404, not found. Any ideas what might be missing?

Old code:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = ApiAuthServerApplication.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest("{server.port:0, server.address:localhost}")
public class ApiEndpointTests {

    @Value("${local.server.port}")
    private int port;

    private RestTemplate template = new TestRestTemplate();

    @Test
    public void clientsEndpointProtected() {
        ResponseEntity<String> response = template.getForEntity("http://localhost:"
                + port + "/uaa/api/v1/oauth/clients", String.class);
        assertEquals(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, response.getStatusCode());            
    }
}
```

The new code I tried:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = ApiAuthServerApplication.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class ApiEndpointTests {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    private TestRestTemplate template = new TestRestTemplate();

    @Test
    public void clientsEndpointProtected() {
        ResponseEntity<String> response = template.getForEntity("http://localhost:"
                + port + "/uaa/api/v1/oauth/clients", String.class);
        assertEquals(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, response.getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

Also tried to `@Autowire` the TestRestTemplate and omit hostname and port in the requests.

Comment: You should only need to `@Autowire` the `TestRestTemplate` instead of creating a new instance, Spring Boot should then properly fix the URL and you could call `/uaa/api/v1/oauth/clients`.

Comment: I have tried this before, and I get the same result

Answer (score 2):

When you use the WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT the sprint test framework will handle the configuration and setup of the host and port.  Therefore you can remove the the details of the host and port.   You should also use the @Autowired annotation on the TestRestTemplate.

```
@Autowired for the TestRestTemplate.

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = ApiAuthServerApplication.class, webEnvironment = 
SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class ApiEndpointTests {

  @Autowired
  private TestRestTemplate template = new TestRestTemplate();

  @Test
  public void clientsEndpointProtected() {
    ResponseEntity<String> response = 
    template.getForEntity("/uaa/api/v1/oauth/clients", String.class);
    assertEquals(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, response.getStatusCode());
  }
}
```

Comment: Getting the same result as before (404 Not found) in the responseCode

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

When using this code:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = ApiAuthServerApplication.class, webEnvironment = 
SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class ApiEndpointTests {

  @Autowired
  private TestRestTemplate template;

  @Test
  public void clientsEndpointProtected() {
    ResponseEntity<String> response = 
    template.getForEntity("/uaa/api/v1/oauth/clients", String.class);
    assertEquals(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, response.getStatusCode());
  }
}
```

I also needed to remove `/uaa` since this is the context path. I guess `TestRestTemplate` includes that as well automatically. So the final code that worked:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = ApiAuthServerApplication.class, webEnvironment = 
SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class ApiEndpointTests {

  @Autowired
  private TestRestTemplate template;

  @Test
  public void clientsEndpointProtected() {
    ResponseEntity<String> response = 
    template.getForEntity("/api/v1/oauth/clients", String.class);
    assertEquals(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, response.getStatusCode());
  }
}
```